# probability problem with students

Tags: probability

The problem is solved independently by 2 excellent students, 3 middle students and 5 students who study well. The probability of solving the problem by an excellent student is 0.9, a good student - 0.8, middle - 0.5. One of the students is called to the blackboard at random. 1) Find the probability that he resolve the problem. 2) The student resolved the task. Find the probability that he is: a) an excellent student; b) a middle student.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve the problem (a) it is enough to do an average of the three probabilities (total probability theorem)

$0.9\times \frac{2}{10}+0.5\times \frac{3}{10}+0.8\times \frac{5}{10}=a+b+c$

The conditional probabilities are:

1. Excellent student: $\frac{a}{a+b+c}$
2. Middle student: $\frac{b}{a+b+c}$
3. Study Well student: $\frac{c}{a+b+c}$